# Prototype handler not initiating on custom emitter

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the following code I'm expecting console.log to output the data that is passed along with the custom emitter 'output' but that's not occurring. From what I can tell Looper.prototype.output is called properly from withing the server handler but it's not responding to the emitter 'output' event that's defined in Looper.prototype.run. Why isn't my output event handler recognizing these events?

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var util = require('util');
var fs = require('fs');
var EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;
var sys = require("sys");

function Looper(req)  {
    this.req = req;
    EventEmitter.call(this);
}
sys.inherits(Looper, EventEmitter);

Looper.prototype.run = function() {
    var cmd = spawn('./flow',[this.req]); // <-- script that outputs req every second
    cmd.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
    cmd.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        this.emit('output',data);
    });
}

Looper.prototype.output = function(callback) {
    this.on('output', function(data) {
        return callback(data.trim());
    });
}

var looper = new Looper('blah');
looper.run();

var app       = express();
var webServer = http.createServer(app);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send(
    "<h1>hello world</h1>"
    );

    looper.output(function(res) {
        console.log('blah');
        console.log(res);
    });
});
webServer.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Looper.prototype.run = function() {
    var cmd = spawn('./flow',[this.req]); // <-- script that outputs req every second
    cmd.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
    cmd.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        this.emit('output',data);
    //  ^ not what you think it is.
    });
}
```

I think that `this` is not what you think it is in that callback.  You need to capture the value of this outside of the callback first.

```
Looper.prototype.run = function() {
    var self = this; // save this
    var cmd = spawn('./flow',[this.req]); // <-- script that outputs req every second
    cmd.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
    cmd.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        self.emit('output',data); // use previously saved value of this
    });
}
```

Otherwise, `this` would default to the global object, and when the global object emits an event, noone is listening to it.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. Now I have another problem. When I start /stop multiple connections to the server I'm seeing the following:
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
Trace

Comment: Well that's a whole 'nother question :)

Comment: yea, it is. i just didn't want to open another q. I'll see if I can solve it tomorrow before I do that.

Comment: If you have two very different problems with the same snippet of code, it works best to ask two questions around these parts.

Comment: I added a new question from this liek you suggested and updated the code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21409828/eventemitter-memory-leak-on-server-handler-that-needs-dynamic-value